# Calculating the percent of a polygon that is contained within a grid cell in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, vector-grid

I have a polygon that covers a grid that I've created.

[image]

I want to find the percent of the polygon's area that is contained within each grid cell. I've tried overlap analysis in QGIS but this returns to me the percent of the grid cell that is covered by the polygon. When I switch the input layer to the polygon and the overlay layer to the grid, it simply returns one line with a 100% overlap, indicating that the grid covers 100% of the polygon.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workflow on how to do it:

- Select the grid polygons that intersect the big polygon ([Select by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location)).
- Use the [Union](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union) tool only on the selected grid polygons.
- Open the attribute table of the output grid polygons after the Union.
- Recalculate the area of the cut grid polygons.
- Add a new column to calculate the percentage. The total of those polygons located inside the main polygon should be equal. You can do a proportional calculation to get the percentage.